# WMS not working in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

When I try to load this WMS: https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?VERSION=1.0.0 in QGIS, I get the following error message:"mswmsloadgetmapparams() image handling error. unsupported output format". In ArcMap the WMS works without issues. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested the WMS service in QGIS 3.16 and  got an error message for version 1.0.0 when trying to load the layers.
If you change the link to https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?VERSION=1.1.0 the layers just work fine in QGIS.

Comment: Thank you, changing the version in the link also fixes the error for me!

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look at the capabilities files [version 1.0.0](https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?VERSION=1.0.0&request=getcapabilities&service=WMS) supports only `<Format><PNG /><JPEG /><SVG /></Format>` while [version 1.1.0](https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?VERSION=1.1.0&request=getcapabilities&service=WMS)  supports:

```
  <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
  <Format>image/gif</Format>
  <Format>image/png</Format>
  <Format>image/pnga</Format>
  <Format>image/png; mode=32bit</Format>
  <Format>image/tiff</Format>
  <Format>image/png; mode=8bit</Format>
  <Format>image/vnd.jpeg-png</Format>
  <Format>image/vnd.jpeg-png8</Format>
  <Format>application/x-pdf</Format>
  <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
  <Format>application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml</Format>
  <Format>application/vnd.google-earth.kmz</Format>
  <Format>application/x-protobuf</Format>
  <Format>application/json</Format>
```

which is much more likely what QGIS sends, to be sure you could try connecting with both end points and then using the Network Activity plugin to check the actual format requested.